# Photoshop - simple Open File action on MAC

Tags: photoshop

Could anyone send the ATN file with only one action -> opening PSD file on Mac?

I've made an action with a lot of steps, it's working good but only on Windows. There is no relative paths in PS actions, and i have no friend that has Mac. Could anyone prepare ATN file (so i will be able to copy "open psd file" step)?

Regards,
Luke

Comment: As you mentioned, you can't use relative paths, so the Mac version of the Open File is also going to be for a particular file. Maybe you want to use Insert Menu Item option?

Comment: Sergey - for Mac i will be happy with absolute path (but ofcourse Mac path). But i can't do it on Windows.

Comment: But you didn't specify a path. If you think that "Open file" action on Mac will be different, you're wrong: it's the same code, and path is the same decoded string (for example `/Library/Application Support` on Mac and `/C/Program Files/Adobe` on Windows). I think your problem is with something else.

Comment: Thank You Sergey for response. Right now the first step I have: OPEN -> C:/PSD/psd.psd. And on my windows i have directory PSD (on disk C) with file psd.psd. 
I would like to change this path on mac. Can be static (so the mac user will have to create folder and copy psd.psd file there), but i have no idea what is the structure in mac.

F.E. i tried to find some common path in Mac on internet, and i think on all Macs there has to be /Users folder. So is there a possibility to copy psd.psd file to /Users folder and make action step with opening this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: this won't work. Even though Photoshop has "shortcuts" paths that are similar for both OSX and Windown (like `~/Desktop` is a shortcut for desktop folder no matter of OS and username), Actions don't seem to recognize them. Furthermore, if you record an `Open` Action on Windows or Mac and open it in a different OS, you'll get a `File or folder not found` message for this step:

Here're two examples. In bot cases the top Action was made in Windows and the bottom one on Mac. This is a Mac screenshot:

[image]

and Windows:

[image]

Notice how `Action1` on the Mac screenshot has `File or folder not found` message and on Windows there's the same message for `Action2` from `fromMac` set.

Here's what you can do though.

- insert Open as a `Menu Item`. This way user will be asked for a file you need every time a user calls the Action.
- give the file you need to open as a pattern file (`.pat`) and ask a user to install it. This way you can fill a document with it using the `Fill` command.
- most powerful: use a script. You can convert your action to a script file using [the xtools](http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html): there's a script within it called `ActionToJavascript`: this will give you a `.jsx` file that you can use in Photoshop and that will work exactly as your action. And in this script you can specify a path for your action. Like here I'm specifying a file on my Desktop:

[image]

And this script will work on Mac.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your answer. I will try to do it via pattern. 

Maybe i wasn't too clear - the result is sattisfy for me to work ONLY on Mac, that's why i asked for a step with opening psd file on Mac. I understand that with Windows path action won't work on Mac and with Mac path won't work on Windows.